# Sending url string via AJAX to PHP

Tags: php, json, ajax, web

I want to send url's string via PHP(this must return a JSON),but I guess there is an encoding issue.
I use file_get_contents("php://input") in my PHP to get the string of this url.But it's impossible.This code is working when I am sending a JSON to PHP.Is there an encoding problem?

```
var urlString='https://google.com';

 $.ajax({
    type        : 'POST',
    url         : 'https://example.php',
    //contentType: 'application/json',
    data: urlString ,                    //I want to send this
    dataType: 'json'

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data for ajax needs to be in json format

```
var urlString='https://google.com';

$.ajax({
type        : 'POST',
url         : 'https://example.php',
data: {"url":urlString} ,                 
dataType: 'json'

});
```

then in your php use
$url = $_POST["url"];

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO!

I think the issue is with your formatting of urlString.

Normally you would want to form it with a key and value, such as:

```
var urlString = 'url=https://google.com';
```

The url you are POSTing data to will usually require that key.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$url = file_get_contents('your-url', false);
$json = json_decode($url, true);
$var = implode(" ",$json);
```